# Window moves to right when I'm clicking tab (focus on the elements outside of the visible window)

Tags: html, css, position, width, sticky

I'm trying to make something similar to a nav that slides in from the right side.

```css
html, body{
    min-height:100%;
}

body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.recipe-bg{
    width:calc(100vw + 270px); // window width + recipe-container width so that it can be hidden
    min-height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    pointer-events:none;
}

.recipe-bg-padding{ // so that recipe-container stops when there is nav at the top
    width:100%;
    height:535px; // nav + banner + 100px
}

.recipe-container{
    width:270px;
    position:sticky;
    top:50px;
    left:100%;
    z-index:90000;
    pointer-events:auto;
}

.rc-extended{
    left:calc(100vw - 270px); // class added in js - moves recipe-container so it's touching the right side of the window
}

.rc-button{
    position:absolute;
    height:50px;
    width:30px;
    top:40px;
    left:-30px;
}

.rc-button img{
    width:80%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Some normal website content</p>
  <p>Some normal website content</p>
  <p>Some normal website content</p>
  
  <div class="recipe-bg">
    <div class="recipe-bg-padding"></div>
    <div class="recipe-container">
      <div class="rc-button">
        <img src="Images/list-arrow-b.svg" alt="arrow">
      </div>
      <div class="delete-div">
        <input type="password" id="password" class="delete-stay">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I don't think that I need to show JS - it just adds the class button click, so that the recipe-container is visible on the right side of the window. The problem is that when I'm using tab (to move focus, like inputs, links, etc.) it moves the window to the right side (so the recipe-container is visible, I can't click the button to hide it, because it's already in its hidden position). Sometimes it happens for no reason after I refresh the page or just use the page. Refreshing the page doesn't work, I have to delete at least 1 character from the browser search bar, click enter and type it again (hard reload won't work). How can I make it so the website content is always sticking to the left side of the screen?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but the reason it moves to the right is because of the `<input>` in that section of the page. You can add `tabindex="-1"` to that `<input>` to prevent the [Tab] key from moving the page over there, but you will not be able to press [Tab] to navigate to that `<input>` anymore (which I'm not sure if that is desired or not)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'd rather have a different solution. It's not like I have to navigate focus via tab to that input, but there is something else causing this problem too. I'm not sure what, sometimes the same happens on page reload, sometimes when I use the page (type something, send form (excluding this input) via ajax, etc. - things not related to that input). Is there a way to just force the content to stick to the left?

Comment: Usually, when on page reload etc. it doesn't move the window all the way to the right, but rather moves content by 10-100px, so the recipe-container is visible only partially.